# can't get text from SPAN tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The structure of the website I'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr height="25">
        <td class="th" style="border:none" width="2%"> </td>
        <td class="th">movie</td>
        <td class="th"> </td>
        <td class="th"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="place_1">
        <td style="color: #555; vertical-align: top; padding: 6px">
            <a name="1"></a>1.
        </td>

        <td style="height: 27px; vertical-align: middle; padding: 6px 30px 6px 0">
            <a class="all" href="/326/">MOVIE TITLE IN SPANISH</a>

            <br/>

            <span class="text-grey">MOVIE TITLE IN ENGLISH</span> 
        </td>

        <td style="width: 85px">
            <div style="width: 85px; position: relative">
                <a class="continue" href="/326/votes/">
                    9.191
                </a> 

                <span style="color: #777">
                    (592 184)
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

The problem is I can't get the text inside span-tag. I've tried **.text** as for a-tag, also tried **.get_text()**. But none of these worked. My code on Python:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:

    info = row.find_all('td')

    movies.append({
        'spn_title' : info[1].a.text,
        'eng_title' : info[1].span.text,
    })
```

The errors I get:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

or

> 'eng_title' : info[1].span.text AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Also, check your soup variable because I can run your code without problem. I suspect that somewhere later in the HTML you don't have one of these present in a row.

---

If the class names are consistent you could filter only qualifying rows having the appropriate type elements with those classes.Using bs4 4.7.1.

```
for row in table.select('tr :has(span.text-grey):has(a.all)'):
    movies.append({
        'spn_title' : row.select_one('.all').text,
        'eng_title' : row.select_one('.text-grey').text
    })
print(movies)
```

---

Otherwise, you want a way to handle if not present. For example,

```
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
     movies.append({
        'spn_title' : row.select_one('.all').text if row.select_one('.all') is not None else 'None',
        'eng_title' : row.select_one('.text-grey').text if row.select_one('.text-grey') is not None else 'None'
    })
print(movies)
```

---

Comment: FYI, you can could condense that selector a bit `tr :has(span.text-grey, a.all)`. `:has()` accepts a relative selector list.

Comment: The first solution returns duplicate rows, so every movie is printed twice. The 2nd solution works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you so much!!! But what's the problem with span tags after all?

Comment: you were selecting in some cases where an item was not present I suspect

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```
info[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML
```

should work.

Comment: 'eng_title' : info[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I was able to resolve it.
example

```
<span class="a-offscreen">$10.99</span>
```

instead of `Elem.FindElementByCss("span.a-offscreen").Text`
use:

```
Elem.FindElementByCss("span.a-offscreen").FindElementByXPath("parent::*").Text
```

The trick is to get the text of the parent.

Btw, I am using VBA so you need to change it to Python Syntax.